# How to parse dynamodb result to an integer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-go

I'm unable to unmarshall a fairly simple data structure:

```
"video_lite": { "id": 1573, "name": "Blade Runner (Movie)" }
```

Here's my code that doesn't work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"
)

type Video struct {
    video_lite struct {
        name string
        id   int
    }
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
}

func main() {

    svc := dynamodb.New(session.New())

    input := &dynamodb.GetItemInput{
        Key:                  map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{"uuid": {S: aws.String("d610e853-5222-462c-9bb3-26ff5aa86e9d")}},
        ProjectionExpression: aws.String("video_lite"),
        TableName:            aws.String("staging_video_ingestion"),
    }

    result, err := svc.GetItem(input)
    check(err)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result.Item)
    var t Video

    err = dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(result.Item, &t)
    check(err)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", t)

}
```

The output looks like:

```
map[video_lite:{
  M: {
    id: {
      N: "1573"
    },
    name: {
      S: "Bladerunner (Movie)"
    }
  }
}]
{video_lite:{name: id:0}}
```

Why doesn't the [UnmarshalMap](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute#UnmarshalMap) work?

Answer (score 1):

[Unmarshal](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute#Unmarshal) instead of [UnmarshalMap](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute#UnmarshalMap) appears to be easier to work with.

```
type Video struct {
    Name string `dynamodbav:"name"`
    ID   int    `dynamodbav:"id"`
}
```

I threw in the [dynamodbav struct tags](https://godoc.org/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute#Marshal) in an act of desperation. It appears they are not needed when unmarshalling. And now I return the map value, instead of the whole map **result.Item** which I never figured out how to get to work with *UnmarshalMap*. :/

```
err = dynamodbattribute.Unmarshal(result.Item["video_lite"], &t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can modify your struct to this :

```
  type Video struct {
      video_lite struct {
        name struct {
           N *string
           S *string
        }
        id struct {
           N *string
           S *string
        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Tried that `{video_lite:{name:{N:<nil> S:<nil>} id:{N:<nil> S:<nil>}}}` was the output.  Also tried dropping down `video_lite` and got `{name:{N:<nil> S:<nil>} id:{N:<nil> S:<nil>}}` :/